# Issue to get data in object from local file

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

I am working with `UITableView` and try to load data from local .json file.

My .json file name is **Result.json**. But I could not get json data using `JSONDecoder().decode`.

Result.json has one Array named "result". And I have to add that result in my **self.resultArray**.

I have tried somecode :

```
  let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Result", withExtension: "json")!
        let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        do {
            let jsonFromWeb = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSONFromWeb.self, from: jsonData)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.resultArray = jsonFromWeb.result
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: What the problem ? and post the json content , the model `JSONFromWeb`

Comment: I can't  get data in jsonFromWeb. I don't know where I am wrong. It goes in catch error.

Comment: @KunwarJungSaroj You need to [edit] your question with more details. What actually happens when you run this code? Assuming you used the debugger to step through this code, where does it go wrong? What messages are shown? Put those details in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `JSONDecoder`.

Please check my updated code:

```
   let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: url, options: .mappedIfSafe)
      do {
      let jsonFromWeb = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData)

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.resultArray = jsonFromWeb.result
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
 } catch {
      print(error)
 }
```

Note: You have to serialize your JSON.

Comment: What is `result`? `jsonFromWeb` will either be an array or a dictionary. Neither have a `result` property. This answer makes no attempt to explain what was wrong in the OP's code and it makes no attempt to explain why this answer solves the problem.

Comment: I just help him to fetch data from json file using path and I help to @Kunwar Jung Saroj using update code with serialize Json instead of JSONDecoder.

Comment: this code won't compile and it's not better than `Decoder`

Comment: But this code doesn't compile and it doesn't explain anything. Good answers should work and good answers should explain.

Comment: @Kunwar - don't accept an answer just because it was posted. Only accept an answer that actually solves your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy It work and not I print my json data before that in my code It did not work and went in catch error. But R. Patel 's updated code gives me data so I accept his answer and its solve my issue. I appreciate you all. I will explain my question in details although its solved.

Comment: the above answer gives the print in `Any` type but doesn't create an object from the data as the decoder would do post your json if you need a correct answer

Comment: @Sh_Khan I got your point but he want to get data from local file so I suggest him to use JSONSerialization. I put print statement for just him hint. Thank you for your  instruction.